# iOS9: Centering programmatically added view inside another programmatically added view

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, ios9

I have a horizontal stackview. I add UIViews to the stackview programmatically. The added UIViews also contain a third view, an UIImageView. The UIImageView is scaled programmatically to a smaller size (height = width = StackView's height).

I would like to centre the UIImageView inside the UIView. But right after adding the UIImageView to the UIView, the UIView does not have any size assigned to it and I cannot figure out how to centre it properly.

I have tried adding flexible margins and tested some constraints.

What other options do I have?

```
let wrapView = UIView()
let image = images[i]
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

wrapView.addSubview(imageView)
miniPicturesView.addArrangedSubview(wrapView)
```

Image related: the blue square should be in the centre of the rectangle.
The square is the UIImageView and the rectangle is the UIView. The three UIViews are inside a horizontal stackview.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you could do something with auto-layout, but when you have a view that has subviews that need to be positioned within it, subclassing UIView is a better way to go in my opinion. (the two approaches aren't exclusive, you could use auto-layout within the subclass if you wanted)

Your wrap view could be an instance of the below CenterView class:

```
class CenterView : UIView
{
    var subView: UIView

    init (fromUIView view: UIView)
    {
        self.subView = view;
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 0,height: 0));
        self.addSubview(self.subView);
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        self.subView.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width / 2, y: self.bounds.height / 2)
    }
}
```

After you construct a CenterView by passing your UIImageView into the constructor, it will keep the UIImageView centered within itself.

Comment: That is indeed a clever solution I was trying to avoid for some reason. I guess subclassing views isn't all that bad in iOS.

Comment: subclassing is everywhere, for UIView.. :)    class UILabel : UIView -- UIButton : UIControl -- UIControl : UIView ....